# How to get a particular attribute from an array of array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an Array of Arrays, and each Array consists of objects. Here is a simplified version of what I'm referring to (it is a console.log of my original array) -

```
Array - [Array(2), Array(3), Array(2)]
```

Each Array has objects in the following format (taking the first array from above) -

```
Array(2) - 
0: {name: "test", score:40, date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z"}
1: {name: "test2", score:50 date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

The other arrays are similar with the same attributes and different values.

I am trying to fetch the name attribute from each of these objects. I tried the below code - but I end up getting an undefined value:

```js
const test1= array1.map(x=> x.values) // this gives me the array of arrays
const test2 = test1.map(function(y){return y.name})// this is my attempt to get the 'name' attribute from all of the arrays that include the objects.
```

What am I missing out on here? Is there a better way to get the attribute using arrow functions?

Comment: can you show us a sample output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with some example data that shows what you're working with, and what your expected outcome is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
/* TEST DATA */
array1 = [
  { name: 'test1', score: 40, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
];
array2 = [
  { name: 'test4', score: 50, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { name: 'test5', score: 40, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' }, 
];
array3 = [
  { name: 'test6', score: 50, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { name: 'test7', score: 50, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { name: 'test8', score: 40, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { name: 'test9', score: 50, date: '2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z' },
];

testResults = [array1, array2, array3];

// Solution 

function getListOfName(){
  let names = [];
  testResults.map(testResult => {
    testResult.map(({name}) => {if(name) names.push(name)})
  })
  return names;
}
console.log("Full list of names", getListOfName());

// If you want to restrict to K names from each array
function getFirstKNamesfromArray(limit){
  let names = [];
  testResults.map(testResult => {
    testResult.map(({name}, index) => {
      if(name && (index < limit)) names.push(name)
    })
  })
  return names
}
console.log("First 2 names from each array", getFirstKNamesfromArray(2));
```

Comment: Thanks. Was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: Just curious - is there anyway to get just the first two 'name' values from each array object?

Comment: @221  testResults.map(testResult => {                                                                  testResult.map((test, index) => {if(index<2)names.push(test.name)} )})

Answer (score 11):

**Flatten** it, and `map` it to names or *Vise versa*

First **flatten** it, and `map`

```js
const array = [[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]

var res = [].concat(...array).map(({name})=>name);
console.log(res);
```

Now, `map` it to names and then **flatten**

```js
const array = [[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]

var res = [].concat(...array.map(a=>a.map(b=>b.name)))
console.log(res);
```

Now, In this one, certainly you can notice that we are actually mapping it in each level (we have to, no other way with first map only approach. so we can perform a `reduce` in place of the outer map and `concat` it there itself, so we can avoid the outer `concat` (for flatten) and inner concat will actually flatten it. Here we go:

```js
const array = [[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]

var res = array.reduce((r, a)=>r.concat(a.map(b=>b.name)), []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that map returns an array; you iterate over it. Filter or reduce do the same.

```
const test1= array1.map(x=> x.values) // x doesn't have a property named  "value"
//simply use forEach
array1.forEach((el) => console.log(el.name))
```

If you want to capture the names inside a collection:

```
const let container = [];
array1.forEach((el) => container.push(el.name))
```

A good way to better understand this iterator functions would be to first use loops and then attempt to "translate" your code into one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your first map `x` is an array, not an object. So, there is no `value`. You should map inner arrays then get the desired value.

```js
const arr = [
  [
    {
      name: "test",
      score: 40,
      date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    { name: "test2", score: 50, date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z" }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: "foo",
      score: 40,
      date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    { name: "bar", score: 50, date: "2018-09-18T00:00:00.000Z" }
  ]
];

const test1 = arr
  .map(x => x.map(y => y.name))
  .reduce((acc, el) => [...acc, ...el], []);


console.log(test1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
const arr = [
    [{name: 'a', date:'x'}, {name: 'b', date:'y'}],
    [{name: 'c', date:'x'}, {name: 'd', date:'y'}]
];

const names = arr.map(el => el.map(obj => obj.name));

console.log(names.join());
console.log(names.flat());
```

you can use flat() to keep names in an array or join() to merge the names into a string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. You need to flatten the array structure and map the names.

```js
const array = [[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]

const names = array.reduce((acc, innerArray) => {
  return [...acc, ...innerArray.map(entry => entry.name)]
}, [])

console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test1= array1.map(x=> x.values)
```

This is returning undefined.

```
let requiredArr = [];

let array1 = [Array(2), Array(3), Array(2)]

let test2 = array1.map(x => x.map(y => requiredArr(y.name));
```

**test2 will give the desired result.**

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Koushik's example, with ES2019, you can use flat() to flatten nested arrays:

```js
const array = [[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]
var res = array.flat().map( ({name}) => name );
console.log(res);
```

Or if you have deeper levels:

```js
const array = [[[{name: 'test1'}], {name: 'test2'}], [{name: 'test3'}, {name: 'test4'}]]
var res = array.flat(2).map( ({name}) => name );
console.log(res);
```

And so on.